# Where is Asp.net CouchbaseClient GetView() method?

Tags: asp.net, couchbase

I installed CouchbaseNetClient (for Asp.net) from NuGet, and it is missing the GetView() method.

Has it been removed or renamed to something else?

Comment: Could you share some code?  GetView is still there and is part of the ICouchbaseClient interface.  I verified that 1.2.3 from NuGet does not have an issue...